# Find CKEDITOR Node's (self) inner text

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, nodes

i have a node with inner text and children's also have inner Text.

how can i fetch current nodes inner text **(without children and its inner Text).**

For Example :

```
<myTag> 
myTag Text
<child1>ch1 Text</child1>
<child2>ch2<child3></child3> Text</child2>
some text
</myTag>
```

Required Result (myTag Inner Text Only):
Find inner text of myTag:

```
1.myTag Text
<child1>
2.some text
<child2>
```

Find inner nodes by

```
x=myTagNode.getchildren()
for(var i=0;i<x.count();i++)
{
if(x[i].type==1)
{
alert(x[i].getName());
}
}
```

**How can i get the inner Text (without children inner Text)?**

Comment: @Reinmar Please see this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a treeWalker:

```
var mytag=document.getElementsByTagName("mytag")[0];
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(mytag, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
var nodeList = [];
while(treeWalker.nextNode()) nodeList.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
```